# TFS Build Failing. Not adding specific DLL to Bin directory

Tags: asp.net, dll, tfs

I've been using TFS to deploy both development and stage builds. For some reason it is looking for 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure' all the sudden, although I don't need it locally to run the project.

I've added the mystery DLL (not needed locally) I have checked and 'Copy Local' is set to True.

I can deploy the files through Publish Settings doing a File System publish method and the DLL is published.

However, when I try to push through TFS it is missing that reference to the DLL, all other DLLs copy to the bin folder as expected. I can copy the file over directly into the bin and the site works.

Has anyone experienced this? Might I have settings incorrect in my TFS Build definition? Suggestions?

*NOTE: Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure is not in my local GAC*

Answer (score 0):

I did experience the same thing when I modified my publish file to "Remove additional files at destination", which cleans out everything, and realized that my manual publish was what actually put the files into place.  The solution that I found to get "copy local" working and publishing was to set copy local to false and then flip it back to true.  This modified the csproj file so that a new element appeared:

```
 <private>true</private>
```

I credit [this post](http://geekswithblogs.net/robz/archive/2008/08/19/tfs-2005-team-build-error-referenced-assembly-missing-not-in.aspx) for helping me figure it out.